# c++ std::cmp_less misbehaving for __int128 depending on standard compiler switch

Tags: c++, c++20, 128-bit

The following short program

```cpp
#include <cstdint>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>
int main() {
__int128 a = -1; 
__int128 b = 1; 
if (std::cmp_less(a, b)) { 
    std::cout << "less" << std::endl;
}
}
```

compiles if I use `-std=gnu++2b` (or even `-std=gnu++20`) but fails with `-std=c++20` or `-std=c++23`:

```
In file included from <source>:2:
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/include/c++/13.2.0/utility: In instantiation of 'constexpr bool std::cmp_less(_Tp, _Up) [with _Tp = __int128; _Up = __int128]':
<source>:11:18:   required from here
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/include/c++/13.2.0/utility:141:49: error: static assertion failed
  141 |       static_assert(__is_standard_integer<_Tp>::value);
      |                                                 ^~~~~
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/include/c++/13.2.0/utility:141:49: note: 'std::integral_constant<bool, false>::value' evaluates to false
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/include/c++/13.2.0/utility:142:49: error: static assertion failed
  142 |       static_assert(__is_standard_integer<_Up>::value);
      |                                                 ^~~~~
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/include/c++/13.2.0/utility:142:49: note: 'std::integral_constant<bool, false>::value' evaluates to false
Compiler returned: 1
```

Can someone shed some light why this happens?

https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/WYMjjsenP

Comment: `__int128` is not a standard type name, it's a GNU extension and reserved for private library use.

Comment: @273K that's completely untrue, it's not reserved for the implementation's use, it's a supported and documented extension type: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fint128.html

Comment: @JonathanWakely Your words "completely untrue" are completely wrong. You try to rebut 1/3 of my comment, "is not a standard type name" is true, "it's a GNU extension" is true, you believe "reserved for private library use" is untrue. The word "completely" is used absolutely incorrectly.

Comment: The claim that it's reserved for private library use is completely untrue, the rest of your comment is true.

Comment: @JonathanWakely What is more important, the standard or GCC extension? [lex.name.3.1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/lex.name#3.1) Each identifier that contains a double underscore __ or begins with an underscore followed by an uppercase letter is reserved to the implementation for any use.

Comment: It's reserved to the implementation to use, and in this case the implementation uses it for an extension type for you to use in your own code. You're not allowed to define something new things using the name `__int128` but if the implementation gives you a type with that name and tells you it's OK to use it, then it's OK to use it. Your claim that it's for private library use is not supported by the standard, or the GCC manual, or the facts being explained by somebody who actually implements the library you're making false claims about.

Answer (score 1):

`__int128` is not a standard type, so when you're in strict standard mode (`-std=c++20`) it won't work.  The only suprise is that it doesn't give an error on the declarations of `a` and `b`.

You need to enable GNU extensions (with `-std=gnu++20` or similar) to make it work, as you have already discovered.

Comment: It doesn't give an error on the declarations of `a` and `b` because the type `__int128` still exists in strict modes, it just isn't considered an integer type by the standard library. The `cmp_less` function is constrained to only work for integer types.

Comment: Yes, you need `-pedantic -Werror` along with `-srd=c++20` to get it to reject everything that is not allowed per the standard.  But in general, you can't expect any g++ extensions to work properly if you use `-std=c++20`